# Three-frame temporal erosion for temporal camera noise reduction

Tags: opencv, image-processing

According to the paper in the  [link](http://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sapphire/pubs/UCRL-CONF-200706.pdf), to reduce temporal camera noise reduction, three-frame temporal erosion is applied (Page 6, last paragraph). A brief description is replacing the image I(t) with the minimum of I(t-1), I(t) and I(t+1). I am not clear how it is implemented. Can somebody suggest me how to implement in a program?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should maintain some stack or list that contains the 3 latest frames I(t-1;:), I(t;:), I(t+1,:) for times (t-1,t,t+1). Then, compute the current image estimate Clean(t;x,y) for each pixel (x,y) as the minimum for the pixel along time:

```
Clean(t;x,y) = min{ I(t-1;x,y), I(t;x,y), I(t+1;x,y) }
```

This is an application of the definition of erosion (put the structuring element, take the min value of the pixels that belong to the structuring element), except that the structuring element is elongated in time.

Comment: In case of the structuring element is elongated in time, how to handle it?

Comment: By applying the formula in the answer (grey part): find the mean along time in a 3-frames window.